# How to extract user characteristics (how fast a user fills a textview etc)

Tags: android

I created an application and in my login page, I want to analyze in how many seconds user enters his password and/or how much pressure he is applying to the keyboard when entering a text etc to check if it is a fraud attempt to log in? My question is, are there any libraries or API's that lets me get this kind of info about the user and what permissions should I put in my manifest file?
 Some of the features I imagine that would be useful are:

- Amount of time to enter password or letter for second

  - In what angle, the user is holding the phone (maybe orientation though this is easy to get)
  - How much pressure he/she is applying to keyboard

There may be many more features but these are the ones that immediately came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most Android phones do not support pressure sensitivity. So I wouldn't use this as a filter. `MotionEvent().getPressure(i)` will return a value between 0 and 1 if the screen is pressure sensitive. I will return 0 or 1 if it is not.
2. For detecting the phone's orientation you can check out this handy gyroscope example https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sensors-in-depth-proximity-and-gyroscope--cms-28084
3. For getting the speed of how fast characters are being inputted into your screen you can fire a timer interval from the moment the user inputs the first character to the moment the user submits the input.
   However, I don't think I can advice this because you would also be filtering out any people who use voice to text, or other handicap features.

Cheers.